# heroku's facebook default template: IE loops authentication and works fine on chrome/firefox

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, heroku

I am working on a facebook app and using chrome everything is fine. On IE and found that the authentication seems to be stuck in a constant loop.

I re grabbed the heruko default template and found the same behaviour.

[Example](https://apps.facebook.com/192658744196642/)

This example only has divs added. None of heroku's php has been touched.

I'm not sure what to do to fix this behaviour.

Comment: I’d like to bet it’s the _third party cookies_ problem all over again. Please use that term for your search.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, that was exactly the problem. All working now... except of course for Safari. I just have a notice to safari users to check their cookie settings.

Comment: Can you explain what the solution was?  I have the same problem..

Comment: Hi v2k, sorry for the delay. I'm swamped with projects.
Add this to the first php block in your fb index.php
`//for IE iFrame 3rd party cookie blocking
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the first php block in your fb index.php. It will fix your IE issue.

`//for IE iFrame 3rd party cookie blocking header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`

This will not solve issues with peope that have third party cookies turned off. e.g. Safari users where third party cookies is off by default.

The way I handled this is to check what browser the user is on and add an alert or extra element to the app. The later will reatedly reload so it's not as easy to read.

An excellent resource for browser detection is Serban Ghita's [php-mobile-detect](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/)